# Jquery windows.width(height) with overflow

Tags: jquery, html, css

i have a problem with the size of window. I am taking size of window like this

```
var boxwidth = $(window).width();
var boxheight = $(window).height();
```

And then create a `canvas`

```js
var canvas: document.createElement("canvas"),
  start: function() {
    this.canvas.width = boxwidth;
    this.canvas.height = boxheight;
    this.context = this.canvas.getContext("2d");
    document.body.insertBefore(this.canvas, document.body.childNodes[0]);
  }
```

But i got overflow to width and height.

I want to create canvas which fit perfectly a window size. Now, i got a lot of overflow

[image]

I already add a `margin:0` and `padding:0` to `body`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, I tried to find a "normal" solution but I didn't found, so here is a "tricky" solution. This is an idea but I assome that you will need to customize it so it will fit to your project.

The logic is to create a `div` that it will take the full width and height of the document and set the canvas dimensions according to it. The final step is to restore the states of the elements (html, body etc.)

So:

```js
$('html, body').css({position: 'relative', height: '100%', overflow:'hidden'});
var tester = $('<div style="width:100%;height:100%" />').appendTo(document.body);
$('canvas').css({
  width:$('body').width(),
  height:tester.height()
});
tester.remove();
$('html, body').removeAttr('style');
```

```css
html, body {
  margin:0;  
}

canvas {
  background:red;
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<canvas></canvas>
```

http://jsbin.com/pinide/edit?html,css,js

Comment: this is tricky solution for now i just find a perfect value to fit without overflow

Answer (score 0):

Adding `<!DOCTYPE html>`at the top of your html file should help.